# “is” vs “it’s” after conjunctions

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, subjects

Which examples are correct and why?

The staff is welcoming, and *is* very easy to contact them by phone.

**vs**

The staff is welcoming, and *it’s* very easy to contact them by phone.

Contacting the staff is not required, but *is* recommended.

**vs**

Contacting the staff is not required, but *it’s* recommended.

I like to dress nice, and *is* great when I get compliments for it.

**vs**

I like to dress nice, and *it's* great when I get compliments for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hopefully you know that "it's" is short for "it is". So you are asking when you can say just "is" and when you have to say "it is". You can only omit the subject when it's the same as the previous subject.

This is wrong:

> I like to dress nice, and is great when I get compliments for it. .

because it means "I like to dress nicely*, and I is great when I get compliments for it." which is incorrect.

However, this is right:

> Contacting the staff is not required, but is recommended.

because it means "Contacting the staff is not required but contacting the staff is recommended". You can also replace the second "contacting the staff" with "it", making both options correct in your second example.

So to answer your question,

> The staff is welcoming, and is very easy to contact them by phone. - **wrong**
>
> The staff is welcoming, and it’s very easy to contact them by phone. - **right**
>
> Contacting the staff is not required, but is recommended. - **right**
>
> Contacting the staff is not required, but it’s recommended. - **right**
>
> I like to dress nice, and is great when I get compliments for it. - **wrong**
>
> I like to dress nice, and it's great when I get compliments for it. - **right**

*It's not in the scope of your question, but as a point of note,  although "dress nice" is used frequently in American English, an adverb is in fact more correct ("dress nicely").

Comment: +1, but OP, I wouldn't recommend saying "dress nicely" in America except when you are being quite formal.

Comment: @hunter Thanks for the clarification, I wasn't sure if it was "widely misused" or "technically wrong but in practice appropriate". I should clarify (since I wasn't explicit in my answer) that it's definitely wrong in UK English.

Comment: I actually learned that fact (about British English still using the adverbs in this type of construction) in a comment thread on this website! In America it's one of those annoying things where grammar teachers say one thing, and so you have to do it that way in formal writing, but in practice almost everyone says it the other way. Of course a language learner can get away with saying something formal in an informal context without coming across as pretentious.

Comment: ` one of those annoying things where grammar teachers say one thing, and so you have to do it that way in formal writing, but in practice almost everyone says it the other way` That's what I meant by "technically wrong but in practice appropriate" - you explained it much better :) ("much more good" in American?)

Comment: lol, we still say better. i think.

Comment: I thought so, but you never know...